# Pass query parameters without using query string form in PHP

Tags: php, html, http

I want to pass parameters using `$_GET` but dont want to use the query form:

```
showevent.php?event=usa
```

should be shown in the url instead want

```
site.com/events/usa
```

And for profiles:

```
site.com/username
```

Comment: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Comment: Do a web search for "php routing" - you'll find loads of libraries. I should think Zend, which is a library of loosely connected components, might have something to offer here. Maybe Symfony2 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser does not know how to format URLs like that. The standard for submitting forms via GET is query strings and that's the only thing your browser can do. Two options:

1. Build the URL via Javascript and redirect the browser programmatically. This has the drawback of requiring a Javascript-capable client.
2. Submit via normal query strings, then on the server rewrite the URL and redirect the client. E.g.:

   ```
   header('Location: /events/' . $_GET['event']);
   exit;
   ```

   This has the drawback of requiring two roundtrips to the server each time and the not-rewritten URL may flash briefly in the user's browsers, but it gets you your nice URL in the end.

You may want a combination of both, with 2. being the fallback for non-Javascript clients.